# Class cannot be resolved in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, session

I have a jsp page and a class. I am trying to use the info of the class in the jsp page. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="user.Customer" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Main Menu</h1>
<% session.setAttribute("username", Globals.customer.getUsername());
   session.setAttribute("password", Globals.customer.getPassword());
   session.setAttribute("name", Globals.customer.getName());
   session.setAttribute("surname", Globals.customer.getSurname());
   session.setAttribute("phone", Globals.customer.getPhone());
   session.setAttribute("address", Globals.customer.getAddress());
   session.setAttribute("email", Globals.customer.getEmail());%>
<a href="editinfo.jsp">Edit your personal information</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Globals class:

```
import user.Customer;


public class Globals {

public static Customer customer;

}
```

Customer class:

```
package user;

public class Customer {

public Customer(){}

public Customer(String username,String password,String name,String surname,String phone,String address,String email){
    this.username=username;
    this.password=password;
    this.name=name;
    this.surname=surname;
    this.phone=phone;
    this.address=address;
    this.email=email;
}

private String username;
private String password;
private String name;
private String surname;
private String phone;
private String address;
private String email;


public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public String getSurname(){
    return surname;
}
public String getUsername(){
    return username;
}
public String getPassword(){
    return password;
}
public String getEmail(){
    return email;
}
public String getPhone(){
    return phone;
}
public String getAddress(){
    return address;
}


}
```

Here is simply what i do: When a user logins, i first create a Customer object by setting its username, email etc. and then i add it to current session. But in the line

```
session.setAttribute("username", Globals.customer.getUsername()
```

it gives an error saying that

```
An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /main.jsp
Globals cannot be resolved
11: <body>
12: 
13:     <h1>Main Menu</h1>
14:     <% session.setAttribute("username", Globals.customer.getUsername());
15:        session.setAttribute("password", Globals.customer.getPassword());
16:        session.setAttribute("name", Globals.customer.getName());
17:        session.setAttribute("surname", Globals.customer.getSurname());
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: Where is the package declaration in your Globals class?

Comment: I don't understand your code block and usage for `Global Class`. Why dont you directly use `instance` from `Customer class`?, as all the `methods` you want to access are defined there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import your `Globals` class as well

```
<%@ page import="user.Customer" %>
<%@ page import="path.to.Globals" %>
```

or, using a *single* page directive for both the imports like

```
<%@ page import="user.Customer,path.to.Globals" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use page directive or extends that jsp page by Globals class.
i.e `<%@page import="package.Globals" %>` 
where package is name of your package..